# Geth: Simulated Backend?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I recently stumbled upon `SimulatedBackend` struct while browsing the code. I noticed that it has a constructor (i.e. `NewSimulatedBackendWithDatabase`) which accepts the path to the node's LevelDB, which is chaindata (right?).

Now, since `SimulatedBackend` provides several functions like `CallContract`, `SendTransaction` etc.,  my guess is that its purpose is to simulate the outcomes of mock transactions, or even contract calls. However, when specifying the path to a runnning node's chaindata, the client failed to start with `resource temporarily unavailable` error. Stopping the node just for this purpose doesn't seem to be a grand idea.

Does anyone have experience with this `SimulatedBackend`? If so, what's the best approach to get it up and running?

Thanks

Comment: Once the simluated backend is up and you've run `backend.Commit()` to produce a block. Then use I'd use `JSONRPC` against the backend to get the chain data

Comment: I believe database in geth is locked, so if you have your node running, and you want to use its chaindata, you need to shut it down first.